# how to configure hibernate session factory with a weblogic datasource that supports Global Transactions

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions

I need to configure hibernate session factory to talk to an existing datasource configured in weblogic 10.3.3.  am using spring 4.x and hibernate 4.x

This datasource supports Global transactions and emulates One-phase commit
Have several questions:
what transaction manager should I use - I am assuming that since my datasource supports Global Tx - it should be a JTA datasource ?

This is what I have:
spring application context:

```
<bean id="sessionFactoryCommon"  
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:COMMON.hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManagerCommon"  
class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebLogicJtaTransactionManager"  />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManagerCommon"  />

<bean id="pitHibDao"
    class="com.abc.PitDaoHibernate"
    lazy-init="true">
    <property name="sessionFactoryCommon" ref="sessionFactoryCommon" />
</bean>
```

The file - COMMON.hibernate.cfg.xml contains:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <!-- this is jndi name of weblogic datasource -->
    <property name="connection.datasource">DSECRDS1</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
    <property name="default_schema">ABC</property>      

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My Dao uses the @Transactional annotation - but when I run this code I get an exception - **org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread**

If I change my datasource to not participate in global transaction - this code works fine - but I need this to work in a datasource that supports global transaction

Comment: Drop your `COMMON.hibernate.cfg.xml` and move the configuration to the spring configuration. Do the JNDI lookup in xml for the datasource and inject it into your `LocalSessionFactoryBean` and inject the transaction manager into the `jtaTransactionManager` property.

Comment: @m-deinum - sorry - I did not understand what you mean by 'inject the transaction manager into the jtaTransactionManager property' ?